# Convert dict to list in flutter?

Tags: python, flutter, dart

How can I convert a Python-like dictionary into a flutter list?
here's my python dict fetched from a dataframe:

```
{0: {'id': '3422',
  'Name': 'John',
  }
 1: {'id': '3322',
  'Name': 'Mark',
  }}
```

I want to convert it in this way:

```
final allUsers = <User>[
  User(id: '3422', name:'John'),
  User(id: '3322', name: 'Mark')]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 dic = {0: {'id': '3422',
  'Name': 'John',},
 1: {'id': '3322',
  'Name': 'Mark',
  }}


flutter_value = ""
f_count = 0
for i in dic:
    f_count+=1
    count = 0
    for j in dic[i]:
        count+=1
        if count == 1:
            flutter_value+='User('+j+":'"+dic[i][j]+"'"
        else:
            flutter_value+=","+j+":'"+dic[i][j]+"')"
    if f_count!=len(dic):
        flutter_value+=","


flutter_value = ("final allUsers = <User>["+flutter_value+"]")
print(flutter_value)
```

Not sure how generic it is, but it can help you in small run I guess.

Output:

```
final allUsers = <User>[User(id: '3422', Name: 'John'),User(id: '3322', Name: 'Mark')]
```

Comment: that's a good one, but would it be possible to remove apostrophes in 'id' and 'Name'??

Comment: @Lash Edited! Lol had to change the entire approach xD

Comment: Amazing! Cheers mate